# (Discord.js) Problem with music command nowplaying

Tags: discord.js

this morning I saw that my discord music bot gave errors when executing the command "nowplaying", that should show the song that is currently playing. (ps: I never changed anything in that command file).

Here is the error:

```
TypeError: createBar is not a function
    at Object.execute (/home/runner/Nightcorer-New/Music/nowplaying.js:60:47)
```

And the code where the error should be:

```
//If its not a stream 
    if (ms > 0 && ms < 10000) {
      nowPlaying.addField("\u200b", "**``[" + createBar((ms == 0 ? seek : ms), seek, 25, "▬", "")[0] + "]``**\n**" + "\n[" + new Date(seek * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8) + " / " + (ms == 0 ? " ◉ LIVE" : new Date(ms * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8)) + "]**" + "\n" + "\n **Time Remaining:**" + "``" + new Date(left * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8) + "``", false);
```

Comment: Where is `createBar` defined?

Comment: oh yea it is defined, on the firsts lines:

const createBar = require("string-progressbar");

Comment: So you are using an external package? If yes make sure it is installed properly and check for any changes in the library. I assume you might have updated the package version and that function is no longer exported or exported in a different way.

Comment: yes, and I just checked, it is installed

Comment: I'll try reinstalling the package

Comment: I reinstalled it and the error is still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As assumed in the comments, the package [string-progressbar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-progressbar) doesn't export one function anymore since [v1.0.3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-progressbar/v/1.0.3). Since [v1.0.4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-progressbar/v/1.0.4) there are an object with two functions exported:

```html
<script type="module">
  import stringProgressbar from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/string-progressbar';
  console.log(stringProgressbar.filledBar(20, 10));
  console.log(stringProgressbar.splitBar(20, 10));
</script>
```

So in order to fix your problem...

- ...update `createBar(...)` to `createBar.filledBar(...)` or `createBar.splitBar(...)`
- ...reinstall [v1.0.3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-progressbar/v/1.0.3) if you want to stick to your old code.